# Remove blank lines in Out-File .txt generated with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm working with a .ps1-Powershell-Script and I'm stuck.

I have following code:

```
$a=0
$b=0
$c=0
$freeRam=0
$strComputer = "localhost"
$date = get-date
$a=Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *freePhysical* | Out-String
$b=Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *totalvisiblememory* | Out-String
$c=Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *LoadPercentage* | Out-String
$a = $a -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
$b = $b -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
$c = $c -replace '\D+(\d+)','$1'
$c = $c.Insert(1,",")
$freeRam=[math]::Round($a/$b*10000)/100 
$seperator="Es ist der " + $date + "; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: " + $freeRam + " % " + "und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell " + $c
$seperator | Out-File -append "D:\Logging\FreeRAM.txt"
```

This code generates a .txt-File with Powershell querying WmiObjects for free physical memory and the actual load percentage for the cpu.

It's working like expected but generates for the win32_processor  LoadPercentage-Query blank linkes.

I've tried using .Trim() for Out-File like this
`$c=Get-WmiObject win32_processor -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *LoadPercentage* | Out-String.Trim()` but that's not working. I've tried using 
-NoNewLine for Out-File like this `$seperator | Out-File -append "D:\Logging\FreeRAM.txt" -NoNewLine` but it's not working.

My Output looks like this:

```
Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:13:31; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.86 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,2




Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:13:35; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.86 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,0




Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:13:39; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.86 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,1




Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:14:00; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.84 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,0
```

And i want it like that:

```
Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:13:31; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.86 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,2
Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:13:35; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.86 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,0
Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:13:39; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.86 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,1
Es ist der 03/04/2019 08:14:00; der verfuegbare Arbeitsspeicher betraegt: 71.84 % und die Auslastung der CPU in % betraegt aktuell 1,0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you variable $c contains empty new lines. For a quick fix, you can add the trim function as follows:

```
  $c = $c.Insert(1,",").trim()
```

Answer (score 3):

*[edit - modified processor load percentage calc to take into account the number of processors.]*

i see that you have your answer ... but the code you used is somewhat more roundabout than seems needed. so i wrote a rather more direct version. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- uses the CIM cmdlets instead of the WMI ones
  CIM is slightly faster than the deprecated WMI calls.
- only calls the `*_OperatingSystem` class once
- gets the `.LoadPercentage` directly
- gets the `.NumberOfProcessors` from `CIM_ComputerSystem`
- calculates the actual load % by summing the [possible] array of `.LoadPercentage` items & dividing by the `.NumberOfProcesors`
- avoids the `Format-List` calls that were inserting the unwanted extra lines
- uses the `-f` string format operator to build the output string

i used english for this since i was uncertain of the wording in your language. i presume you can translate back to yours far better than i can ... [*grin*]

```
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

$CIM_OS = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName
$CIM_CS_ProcessorCount = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem).NumberOfProcessors

$FreeRAM_Pct = [math]::Round($CIM_OS.FreePhysicalMemory / $CIM_OS.TotalVisibleMemorySize * 100, 2)
$ProcLoad_Pct = [math]::Round(((Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Processor -ComputerName $ComputerName).
    LoadPercentage |
    Measure-Object -Sum).Sum / $CIM_CS_ProcessorCount, 2)

'Time stamp = {0}; Free RAM % = {1}; Processor load % = {2}' -f $TimeStamp, $FreeRAM_Pct, $ProcLoad_Pct
```

output ...

```
Time stamp = 2019-03-06 06:18:04; Free RAM % = 43.61; Processor load % = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for improving the script to give it a new touch. I've tested it but it doesn't give  me the right output -> [link](https://i.imgur.com/pnG1fhm.png) Do you know why I get  System.Object[] instead of the processor load?

Comment: @andrk0 - you may have more than one processor. that might give you an array instead of a single number in `$ProcLoad_Pct`. i cannot test that since i have only this one, single-cpu system to work on. ///// what do you get from `(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem).NumberOfProcessors`?

Comment: Return value is 2. Is it possible to get the information from the array by adding the index value like $ProcLoad_Pct[0] and $ProcLoad_Pct[1]?

Comment: @andrk0 - i have changed the c0de above to take into account the number of processors. please test it - i only have one physical CPU, so i am summing only one `.LoadPercentage` & then dividing by only one `.NumberOfProcessors`. [*grin*]

Comment: It's working without error but the processor load seems to be not the truth. It's showing 1,5 % but the task manager says 20% load. Or is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: @andrk0 - i don't know. [*blush*] on my single-cpu system, the code seems to be accurate but i may will have missed something that makes a difference on a multi-cpu system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this construction:

```
$a=(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $strComputer | fl *freePhysical* | Out-String).Trim()
```

Or make the last line:

```
$seperator.Trim() | Out-File -append "D:\Logging\FreeRAM.txt"
```